# Tuple Java like tuple in OPL

Tags: java, tuples, opl

I have coded and run my model in OPL, and I am trying to run code it in JAVA and run it again. As part of my Code (in OPL), I have defined a Tuple as follows:

```
int Y = asSet(1..7);
int k = asSet(1..42);
int G = asSet(1..2);

tuple SL {
    int i;
    int j;
    float l;
}

{SL} SLs with i,j in Y=...; /* e.g. {<1,2,502>, <2,5,309>, <5,7,401>, <2,3,350>} */

Then, I have defined other arrays of:

int u[SLs][G]=...; /* e.g. u[<1,2,502>][1] = 50; u[<1,2,502>][2] = 83; u[<2,5,309>][1] = 75;*/
```

Now that I wanted to code it in Java, I have done it as follows, but I am not sure if I am right. I would appreciate if you could share your ideas.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Model {
    public static int Y = 7;
    public static int K = 42;
    public static int G = 3;
    public static int R = 2;


    public class SL {
        public int i; /* how say i is in Y*/
        public int j; /* how say j is in Y*/
        public int l;

        List<SL> sl = new ArrayList<SL>();

        Object[] SL1 = Sl.toArray(); 
        int [][] u = new int [sL.length][G];

    }

    public static void Solve() {
        /* How to instantiate SL1 and u[<i,j,l> in SL1][g in G] here and printout SL1:*/
    }

}
```

and another class to run the solve() method:

```
public class SolverMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model.Solve();

    }

}
```

I would appreciate if you help me out to fix and run the code.

Regards,
Bornay

Answer (score 1):

You may make Map so that with tuple or object of SL you can generate unique number which can be used as a index in u var. say,

`Map<SL,Integer> m;
int key=m.get(sl);
u[key][g]`

and to instatiate SL1 you need to make object of SL since SL1 is not static.

```
SL sl=new SL();
sl.SL1 or sl.u
```

First create object of SL and point it's variables or methods.

Here is my implemented code below. I have made some changes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Model {

public static int Y = 7;
public static int K = 42;
public static int G = 3;
public static int R = 2;

static Map<SL,Integer> m=new HashMap<>();
static List<SL> sL = new ArrayList<SL>();

static int[][] u;
static int index=0;
static public class SL {

    public int i;
    /* how say i is in Y*/
    public int j;
    /* how say j is in Y*/
    public int l;

}

public static void Solve() {
    /* How to instantiate SL1 and u[<i,j,l> in SL1][g in G] here and printout SL1:*/
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        SL sl=new SL();
        sl.i=i;sl.j=i+1;sl.l=i+2;
        sL.add(sl);
        m.put(sl, index++);
    }
    u=new int[m.size()][G];

    for(SL s:sL){
        for(int i=0;i<G;i++){
            u[m.get(s)][i]=i+10;
        }

    }
    for(SL s:sL){
        for(int i=0;i<G;i++){
            System.out.println(u[m.get(s)][i]);
        }

    }

}
public static void main(String[] arg){
    Model.Solve();
}
}
```

Here I have made sL,m and u static because we need only single instance of it.

Comment: Thanks sminmgr. Would you please instantiate it and printout the small instance given in my problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty confused. Map <Integer,Sleg>, i.e. key ...> int and <i,j,k> ... > Sleg. But, I think your code, ,does not give that. Could you please edit  and share your complete code, which can be run and print  a HashMap and a array u[key][G].

Comment: @B.Bornay I have posted my code. Please see and query for any question.